# cropping image by using a custom view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to crop an image by using a custom view. I have two view controller each of them are ViewController and ResultViewController. viewController has a button and an mageView and the other one has an imageView. when I crop on the ViewController, the results are out of the transparent custom view on the ResultViewController. I don't know where I'm doing wrong or missing. I have changed content mode of the image view to aspect fill, aspect fit, scale to fit and center but the results aren't what I want. Any help would be really appreciated.

**I read the official document** : [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let resultVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "resultVC") as! ResultViewController
    
    var rectangleView: UIView! = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100,y: 200,width: 100,height: 100))
    // this is the transparent custom view as a mask.
    
    @IBAction func okayButton(_ sender: Any) {
        resultVC.resultImage = cropImage(imageView.image!, toRect: rectangleView.frame, viewWidth: self.view.frame.size.width, viewHeight: self.view.frame.size.height)
        print(rectangleView.frame)
        present(resultVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    func cropImage(_ inputImage: UIImage, toRect cropRect: CGRect, viewWidth: CGFloat, viewHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage?
    {
        let imageViewScale = max(inputImage.size.width / viewWidth,
                                 inputImage.size.height / viewHeight)
        
        // Scale cropRect to handle images larger than shown-on-screen size
        let cropZone = CGRect(x:cropRect.origin.x * imageViewScale,
                              y:cropRect.origin.y * imageViewScale,
                              width:cropRect.size.width * imageViewScale,
                              height:cropRect.size.height * imageViewScale)
        
        // Perform cropping in Core Graphics
        guard let cutImageRef: CGImage = inputImage.cgImage?.cropping(to:cropZone)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        
        // Return image to UIImage
        let croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cutImageRef)
        return croppedImage
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let imageFile = UIImage(named: "c.png")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        imageView.image = imageFile
        
        view.addSubview(rectangleView)
        rectangleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
        
        
    }
    
    
}

//ResultViewController
import UIKit

class ResultViewController: UIViewController {
    var resultImage:UIImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultImageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        resultImageView.image = resultImage
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

before cropping[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wX5m.png)

after cropping[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkfV9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an important point here is you have to convert all the frame's rects into the same coordinate system before cropping.

For easy, I'll choose the image as the base coordinate system with the origin is the TOP-LEFT point of the image. Please note that the image I mention here is not the same with the imageView which is used to display the image.

For the crop function, I'll use the one I'm using for [my library](https://github.com/congnd/FMPhotoPicker/blob/master/FMPhotoPicker/FMPhotoPicker/source/ImageEditor/Crop/FMCroppable.swift#L20)

```
public func crop(image: UIImage, toRect rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
    let orientation = image.imageOrientation
    let scale = image.scale
    var targetRect = CGRect()
    
    switch orientation {
    case .down:
        targetRect.origin.x = (image.size.width - rect.maxX) * scale
        targetRect.origin.y = (image.size.height - rect.maxY) * scale
        targetRect.size.width = rect.width * scale
        targetRect.size.height = rect.height * scale
    case .right:
        targetRect.origin.x = rect.minY * scale
        targetRect.origin.y = (image.size.width - rect.maxX) * scale
        targetRect.size.width = rect.height * scale
        targetRect.size.height = rect.width * scale
    case .left:
        targetRect.origin.x = image.size.height - rect.maxY * scale
        targetRect.origin.y = rect.minX * scale
        targetRect.size.width = rect.height * scale
        targetRect.size.height = rect.width * scale
    default:
        targetRect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x * scale,
                            y: rect.origin.y * scale,
                            width: rect.width * scale,
                            height: rect.height * scale)
    }
    
    if let croppedCGImage = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: targetRect) {
        return UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage, scale: scale, orientation: orientation)
    }
    
    return image
}
```

To use the function above correctly with your example, you have to change your implemetation to this. Please read the comments to get the idea.

```
@IBAction func okayButton(_ sender: Any) {
    // Get the rectangeView's frame in the imageView's coordinate system
    let rectangleViewRectInImageView = rectangleView.convert(rectangleView.bounds, to: imageView)
    
    let imageWHRatio = imageView.image!.size.width / imageView.image!.size.height
    let imageViewWHRatio = imageView.bounds.width / imageView.bounds.height
    
    // We are going to calculate the frame of the displayed image content inside the imageView
    var imageRectInImageView: CGRect = .zero
    
    if imageWHRatio > imageViewWHRatio {
        // White spaces in the top & bottom
        imageRectInImageView = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: (imageView.bounds.height - imageView.bounds.width / imageWHRatio) / 2,
            width: imageView.bounds.width,
            height: imageView.bounds.width / imageWHRatio
        )
    } else {
        // White spaces in the left & right
        imageRectInImageView = CGRect(
            x: (imageView.bounds.width - imageView.bounds.height * imageWHRatio) / 2,
            y: 0,
            width: imageView.bounds.height * imageWHRatio,
            height: imageView.bounds.height
        )
    }
    
    // How big the image are being scaled to fit the imageView's bound.
    let imageScale = imageView.image!.size.width / imageRectInImageView.width
    
    // The frame of the rectangeView in the displayed image content view's coordinate system
    let toRect = CGRect(
        x: (rectangleViewRectInImageView.minX - imageRectInImageView.minX) * imageScale,
        y: (rectangleViewRectInImageView.minY - imageRectInImageView.minY) * imageScale,
        width: rectangleViewRectInImageView.width * imageScale,
        height: rectangleViewRectInImageView.height * imageScale)
    
    // Now you have the frame of the rectangleView in proper coordinate system, so you can my method above safely
    resultVC.resultImage = crop(image: imageView.image!, toRect: toRect)
    print(rectangleView.frame)
    present(resultVC, animated: true)
}
```

Please make sure that you have to select `scaleAspectFill` as the `contentMode` for the imageView to make it work correctly.

Comment: thank you very much sir. your explanation is very useful for me to understand. i think i’m getting to be more understanding about this. i implemented your code and it takes a picture of upper area and zoomed up. i did on my real device and simulator and set content mode as AspectFill.. Do i need to take a look at other setup? or am I missing anything else?

Comment: Can you create a sample project and put it to Github or somewhere? It's easy for me to help you.

Comment: sure!! thank you so much. i haven’t used github but i’ll make it and put it on there and let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: I just added the project zip link.

Comment: ah.. maybe I added some pictures and then removed them but not removed from Xcode completely... I think that's why it's that big.. haha

Comment: @ssssw Sorry I forgot to multiply with `imageScale` for the origin point of the `toRect`. I updated the solution. Please take a look. For your project, don't forget that you have to select exact `scaleAspectFit` for both image views in 2 view controllers. Doing you will get the correct one

Comment: thank you so much. I'm sorry to bother you but it doesn't seem working.. I'm not good at calculating but when I do "print(toRect.minY)" at the bottom of okayButton action method, the value is negative. like -323.. the cropped image is out of the custom view.

Comment: It's hard to say what happens on your side with only that information. if you move your `reactangleView` around, then, of course, the `toRect.minY` can be negative.

Comment: I'll constantly keep thinking what the problem is. your code is really helpful. I learned so much from your code. I really appreciate that :)

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. If you can separate the issue, it will become very easy for people to help you. No one wants to see your entire application just to find out 1 issue. So my suggestion is, check carefully each part (or method) of your app, then you can exclude ones that work as you expected.

Comment: my please! and yes that's true. I should start dividing and make them clearly. hopefully I'll get to know where I was wrong :)

Comment: i finally figured out where i was wrong. your code works very well. i set “aspect fill” but changed it “aspect fit” (which definitely is said on your comments) i should have read more carefully. i misread it “aspect fill” could i ask you a question about your code?

Comment: sure. what is your question?